# Why is my for loop leaking?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, instruments, memory-leaks

I have run my program through instruments and it reports a leak in this code:

[image]

Why is that ?

Comment: that looks like CPU utilization, not a leak report.   All the objects there look like they're autoreleased in non-ARC.  Are you using ARC?

Comment: it does not seems to be a leak. check out these similar references: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953519/iphone-substringtoindex-substringfromindex-substringwithrange-memory-leak http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698046/memory-leak-with-substringwithrange-nsstring

Comment: no I am not using ARC...

Comment: I am just guessing leaking might happen due to the characters array.Have look for the flow of the characters array.

Comment: I have no idea, if this is a part of the problem, but u are using stingWithFormat, but the string literal you pass in, isnt a format, try `NSString *answer = @"synthesis";`

Comment: also note, that what you are trying to achieve, could be done by `characters = [answer componentsSeparatedByString:@""];`

Comment: no ... using `characters = [answer componentsSeparatedByString:@""];` does not split up my word into separate characters.

Comment: substringWithRange seems to be the culprit ... Can I ignore this leak ?

Comment: Check Instruments’ object list to find the type of the object you're leaking.

Comment: I am leaking an NSString*... Well to be precise, 8 NSString objects, which are presumably the character chunks.

Comment: @user1066899 `substringWithRange:` doesn't leak. I'll bet you're leaking `characters` and hence everything it contains along with it.

Answer (score 1):

This part of code is not leaking. Try running the analyzer and it might show you what is leaking.

Comment: I'll wager `characters` is leaking. And when that leaks, obviously everything it is solely responsible for retaining also leaks — including all the strings created here.

Answer (score 0):

as I said before, I cant see a leak here, but some code changes might be useful to get rid of the possible leak, as you are assuming `substringWithRange:` is yielding the leak.

The following code uses block-based enumeration. Another positive effect: It know how to handle composed non-ascii chars.

```
NSMutableArray *characters = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *answer = @"Hello, Wørld!";
[answer enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [answer length]) 
                           options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences 
                        usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, 
                                     NSRange substringRange,
                                     NSRange enclosingRange, 
                                     BOOL *stop) 
{
    [characters addObject:substring];
}
 ];


[characters enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@", obj);
}];
```

Comment: well, thank you for this answer, but Instruments still shows 8 leaked NSString objects, which I assume are the chunks my `answer` is broken up into... So... the problem remains :(

Comment: than it must be something else in your code — this, for sure, isn't leaking.

Comment: what are you doing with the characters later?